# How to protect a power supply

Tags: power-supply, safety, ac-dc

Enthusiast here, with no particular electrical engineering knowledge.

I have ordered a power supply, similar to this one in the way it is built:

[image]

Here are the specs:

- Input is 230V AC
- Output is 48V DC / 300W / 8.3A

As you can see from the picture, the AC (and DC) connectors are barely protected (one could easily touch both connectors with their fingers).

**Could anyone recommend a way to protect the device from being touched?**

I've got kids at home and I don't want to take any risks.

Comment: Putting it in a flame-resistant box is the normal method. The data sheet for the power supply should give hints. Please provide a link to it.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you. I will provide it whenever I get it (hoping there will be one!).

Comment: Not the type of protection you're asking about, but a fuse on the mains input would also be a good idea. For building these into an enclosure, I like the combo IEC sockets that include a fuse holder and on/off switch. A metal enclosure will require a protective earth/ground connection (see https://sound-au.com/earthing.htm).

Comment: Nothing is risk-free or child-proof or idiot-proof, but the danger of electrocution from contact with the 220V line voltage could be minimized by covering the connections with electrical grade RTV or other insulating compound. There would still be some risk if someone poked a wire into one of the vent holes, but that would probably cause a short to the grounded case. A GFCI circuit would provide additional protection. But a proper electrical enclosure would be best. Also be careful with the 48V output, which can be hazardous as well.

Comment: Peripheral: The power supply you have shown is "Meanwell" brand. Despite the poor choice of name they are well built and value for money. Your's may or may not be that brand.

Answer (score 12):

It is just a component that can be used to build things.

It is not supposed to be used as-is.

It needs a case around it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140536/discussion-on-answer-by-justme-how-to-protect-a-power-supply).

Answer (score 6):

The PSU is intended to be mounted in an enclosure. As it has a fan for cooling, that enclosure should be ventilated and also be capable of withstanding the maximum temperature produced by the operating PSU.

The type of enclosure is something you must select, as you alone are responsible for the safety of what you have made.

As safety is your question, I'd recommend you buy an enclosed PSU instead.

Answer (score 4):

These types of supplies are built to go in products, most of the time a warning is also attached to the products "no user serviceable parts inside" which prevents people from opening the case and a saftey issue. With kids you'll need to build an enclosure. Digikey or another distributor have [enclosures](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/boxes/594) that might be useful. Another thing is you also might want to put a 230V 15A fused power entry module incase of over current.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you'll need to put that power supply into an enclosure, but there are several things to keep in mind.  Looking at the [datasheet for the supply in your picture](https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/RSP-320/RSP-320-SPEC.PDF) (check the datasheet for the *actual* supply you are using; if there's no datasheet, get a different supply), you can see the mounting configuration drawing:

[image: RSP320 Datasheet Screencap]

I'm not sure what those little dashed "ears" are, probably recommended mounting brackets.  They might be included, but the datasheet doesn't say anything about them.  What you will probably be using are the four M4 holes in a 150mmx50mm rectangle in the middle of the unit.  Pay close attention to the "L=3mm" dimension; those holes are usually threaded inserts that are open on both ends.  If you use a fastener that screws in more than 3mm, you will be grinding the end into the protective plastic sheet over the circuit board.  This can cause damage to the unit and, worst case, cause the screw to contact a line-voltage trace.

Which brings me to my second point: case grounding.  You're asking about 230V, so you're probably not in the US, which means that your code is different (so look up the requirements for your own country) but the rationale is the same: if you were to have a line-voltage conductor contact the case, either by using a too-long mounting screw or maybe your line input wire comes loose, the entire case is now at line voltage and a shock hazard.  If you have a metal case, you will need to ground it.  Here's where the requirements come in for bonding separate case parts together, allowable wire gauge, star configuration, etc.  If you have a plastic case, you *should* be able to avoid much of this, but again, check the requirements for the country you are in.

Comment: This answer assumes that the power supply is the Mean Well RSP-320-24 like in the picture but the picture is just for reference to a similar power supply, which is said to be MSX MXS800.

Comment: ^^ MSX800 to be absolutely correct. Unless I see something different when I get the product in my mail box.

Comment: Good catch, I've updated the answer to reflect this.  Not seeing a datasheet for the MSX800 which is always the sign of a quality product.